# Rate of convergence of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory

Assume $E[X_t-1]=o(t^\alpha)$. Does that imply that $E[(X_t−1)\frac{1}{X_t}]=o(t^\alpha)$ ?

Edit: I also assume that $X_t$ converges to $1$ pathwise.

Comment: I would say no. Optimistically, your hypothesis says that $X_t - 1$ is close to a small number most of the time, and so $X_t$ is bounded away from zero most of the time. This does nothing to make $1/X_t$ integrable, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to construct counterexamples where $X_t = 0$ (or, if you want to disallow that, something very very close to $0$) with positive probability.